PBI DAX show only smallest value of the comminated columns
I need a DAX measure that will calculate the smallest "sort" number of the combined customer and quarter
desired result:

so my this is my code
result = 
VAR _tbl = 
SUMMARIZE(
'BI Booking ACV',
'Dim Installed at Top Account'[Installed at Top Account],
'DateTable'[Quarter Year Name],
'Dim Sales Category'[Sales Category Sort]
)
RETURN
MINX(_tbl,'Dim Sales Category'[Sales Category Sort])

my code isnt good. all it's giving me is the same result as Sort.

Can you please share the relationships between your table ? and some data ?

Is the screenshot your sample data or table visual? If it's the table visual, pls provide some sample data.

there are 3 dims and 1 fact. all dims are connected to the fact.
and i dont know how to add data here
and in the screanshot, the last column is the result im looking for

Could be this or do we have to add anything else?
I've taken dates of quarters as period to don't waste time.
Sort 1 is pretty simple the problem is that the total doesn´t gives you the correct sum.
Sort 2 gives the correct total sum if you need it.


Thanks for answering. this isn't what I mean.
for the combination of customer and period I need only the lowers sort number.
so, for example above, Customer1 has 3 sort numbers for 2024/Q3 - 4,7,8.
I only want to count the smallest sort number.
the final result is me counting the number of customers per sort per time but only taking account the smallest sort number.
so for 2024/Q3 iil count customer1 just once and not 3 times

Something like that?
enter image description here
Number of times appears Account = 

COUNTROWS(Tabla)

With this you've the number of times Account appears.
Now the MIN SORT
MIN SORT = 

var _MIN = CALCULATE(MIN(Tabla[Sort]))

RETURN

SUMX(VALUES(Tabla[Quarter Year]), CALCULATE(MIN(Tabla[Sort])))

With this you are obtaining the MIN SORT Value.
So you have a table where you can see MIN SORT and the number of times that an Account appears at the time period.
To check how appears in the case that you've more than one customer I've add customer 2.
